# cppcheck output paths seem wrong

Tags: c++, path, cppcheck

I am trying to use [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) to analyze my c++ project. My command looks like this:

```
me@home:trunk/software/cpp/tnoid$ cppcheck -v --enable=all --xml -I ../../../package/build/common/cpp/ -I ../../../package/build/software/cpp/tnoid/ .
```

You can see where I include (-I) two additional directories. In the results instead of getting those (unfortunately long) relative paths back, it seems truncated, for example:

```
<error file="/../package/build/common/cpp/libutil/DeleteNullifier.h" line="34" id="postIncrementDecrement" severity="possible style" msg="Pre-Incrementing variable 'iter' is preferred to Post-Incrementing"/>
```

Perhaps I am using cppcheck incorrectly? Why does the file path in the error appear shortened? It's really messing with the cxx sonar plugins.

**EDIT**: This is using cppcheck version 1.40

Comment: Have you tried with absolute paths?

Comment: Yes, if I specify full paths to include, it prints the full absolute path in the output. That may be how I end up doing it, but I wish the relative paths worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as it turns out I needed to upgrade my cppcheck application anyway.

- version in Ubuntu 10.04: 1.40
- Newest cppcheck version: 1.58
- newest sonar-supported: 1.54

Upgrading to 1.54 solved the problem. Relative paths are now correct.